# Connection refused doing a data bulk in elasticsearch using python

Tags: python, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose with two containers, one with python and other one with Elasticsearch. I'm trying to bulk a lot of txt files in the Elasticsearch DB reading it and inserting it line per line, but for some reason the Elasticsearch machine it stops during the bulk and the connection is refused.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 160, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  web:
    container_name: web
    restart: "always"
    build: "./web"
    hostname: web
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - els
    volumes:
      - ./web:/web
      - ./data:/data
    networks:
      - esnet

  els:
    container_name: els
    build: "./containers/elasticsearch"
    restart: "always"
    hostname: els
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    volumes:
      - "./data/elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data"
    ulimits:
      nproc: 3000
      nofile: 65536
      memlock: -1
    environment:
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx8G"
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
    networks:
      - esnet

volumes:
  web:
  data:

networks:
  esnet:
```

This is the elasticsearch dockerfile:

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.2.1

ADD ./elasticsearch.yml /usr/share/elasticsearch/config

EXPOSE 9200 9300
```

And this is the config:

```
http.host: 0.0.0.0

http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-headers: "X-Requested-With, X-Auth-Token, Content-Type, Content-Length, Authorization"
http.cors.allow-methods: "OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE"
http.cors.allow-credentials: true
```

This is my data bulk code:

```
bulk_list = []
with open(file) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    l = line.strip()
    l = l.replace("\n", "")
    if l:
        bulk_list.append({"...some data..."})
helpers.bulk(els, bulk_list)
```

And this is my `http://localhost:9200/_nodes/thread_pool?pretty` write param:

```
"write" : {
    "type" : "fixed",
    "size" : 8,
    "queue_size" : 200
}
```

I think the latter is the problem, but I'm not too sure what is the best way to fix this avoiding the connection refused.

Thanks!

ADDED:

This is the log error in docker-compose:

```
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-05-24T20:04:13,927Z", "level": "ERROR", "component": "o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "els", "message": "fatal error in thread [elasticsearch[els][refresh][T#1]], exiting", "cluster.uuid": "Ic_DMuXJTQqa4zu3wSEobw", "node.id": "12SGfI1qQkyZ-KJjF_okPA" ,
"stacktrace": ["java.lang.InternalError: a fault occurred in a recent unsafe memory access operation in compiled Java code",
"at org.apache.lucene.index.ByteSliceReader.readByte(ByteSliceReader.java:73) ~[lucene-core-8.5.1.jar:8.5.1 edb9fc409398f2c3446883f9f80595c884d245d0 - ivera - 2020-04-08 08:55:42]",
"at org.apache.lucene.store.DataInput.readVInt(DataInput.java:126) ~[lucene-core-8.5.1.jar:8.5.1 edb9fc409398f2c3446883f9f80595c884d245d0 - ivera - 2020-04-08 08:55:42]",
"at org.apache.lucene.index.FreqProxFields$FreqProxPostingsEnum.nextPosition(FreqProxFields.java:501) ~[lucene-core-8.5.1.jar:8.5.1 edb9fc409398f2c3446883f9f80595c884d245d0 - ivera - 2020-04-08 08:55:42]",
"at org.apache.lucene.codecs.PushPostingsWriterBase.writeTerm(PushPostingsWriterBase.java:150) ~[lucene-core-8.5.1.jar:8.5.1 edb9fc409398f2c3446883f9f80595c884d245d0 - ivera - 2020-04-08 08:55:42]",
"at org.apache.lucene.codecs.blocktree.BlockTreeTermsWriter$TermsWriter.write(BlockTreeTermsWriter.java:937) ~[lucene-core-8.5.1.jar:8.5.1 edb9fc409398f2c3446883f9f80595c884d245d0 - ivera - 2020-04-08 08:55:42]",
"at org.apache.lucene.codecs.blocktree.BlockTreeTermsWriter.write(BlockTreeTermsWriter.java:347) ~[lucene-core-8.5.1.jar:8.5.1 edb9fc409398f2c3446883f9f80595c884d245d0 - ivera - 2020-04-08 08:55:42]",
"at org.apache.lucene.codecs.perfield.PerFieldPostingsFormat$FieldsWriter.write(PerFieldPostingsFormat.java:170) ~[lucene-core-8.5.1.jar:8.5.1 edb9fc409398f2c3446883f9f80595c884d245d0 - ivera - 2020-04-08 08:55:42]",
"at org.apache.lucene.index.FreqProxTermsWriter.flush(FreqProxTermsWriter.java:97) ~[lucene-core-8.5.1.jar:8.5.1 edb9fc409398f2c3446883f9f80595c884d245d0 - ivera - 2020-04-08 08:55:42]",
"at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.flush(DefaultIndexingChain.java:177) ~[lucene-core-8.5.1.jar:8.5.1 edb9fc409398f2c3446883f9f80595c884d245d0 - ivera - 2020-04-08 08:55:42]",
"at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.flush(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:468) ~[lucene-core-8.5.1.jar:8.5.1 edb9fc409398f2c3446883f9f80595c884d245d0 - ivera - 2020-04-08 08:55:42]",
"at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.doFlush(DocumentsWriter.java:555) ~[lucene-core-8.5.1.jar:8.5.1 edb9fc409398f2c3446883f9f80595c884d245d0 - ivera - 2020-04-08 08:55:42]",
"at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.flushAllThreads(DocumentsWriter.java:722) ~[lucene-core-8.5.1.jar:8.5.1 edb9fc409398f2c3446883f9f80595c884d245d0 - ivera - 2020-04-08 08:55:42]",
"at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.getReader(IndexWriter.java:494) ~[lucene-core-8.5.1.jar:8.5.1 edb9fc409398f2c3446883f9f80595c884d245d0 - ivera - 2020-04-08 08:55:42]",
"at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.doOpenFromWriter(StandardDirectoryReader.java:297) ~[lucene-core-8.5.1.jar:8.5.1 edb9fc409398f2c3446883f9f80595c884d245d0 - ivera - 2020-04-08 08:55:42]",
"at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.doOpenIfChanged(StandardDirectoryReader.java:272) ~[lucene-core-8.5.1.jar:8.5.1 edb9fc409398f2c3446883f9f80595c884d245d0 - ivera - 2020-04-08 08:55:42]",
"at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.doOpenIfChanged(StandardDirectoryReader.java:262) ~[lucene-core-8.5.1.jar:8.5.1 edb9fc409398f2c3446883f9f80595c884d245d0 - ivera - 2020-04-08 08:55:42]",
"at org.apache.lucene.index.FilterDirectoryReader.doOpenIfChanged(FilterDirectoryReader.java:112) ~[lucene-core-8.5.1.jar:8.5.1 edb9fc409398f2c3446883f9f80595c884d245d0 - ivera - 2020-04-08 08:55:42]",
"at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.openIfChanged(DirectoryReader.java:165) ~[lucene-core-8.5.1.jar:8.5.1 edb9fc409398f2c3446883f9f80595c884d245d0 - ivera - 2020-04-08 08:55:42]",
"at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.ElasticsearchReaderManager.refreshIfNeeded(ElasticsearchReaderManager.java:66) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.ElasticsearchReaderManager.refreshIfNeeded(ElasticsearchReaderManager.java:40) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]",
"at org.apache.lucene.search.ReferenceManager.doMaybeRefresh(ReferenceManager.java:176) ~[lucene-core-8.5.1.jar:8.5.1 edb9fc409398f2c3446883f9f80595c884d245d0 - ivera - 2020-04-08 08:55:42]",
"at org.apache.lucene.search.ReferenceManager.maybeRefreshBlocking(ReferenceManager.java:253) ~[lucene-core-8.5.1.jar:8.5.1 edb9fc409398f2c3446883f9f80595c884d245d0 - ivera - 2020-04-08 08:55:42]",
"at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.InternalEngine$ExternalReaderManager.refreshIfNeeded(InternalEngine.java:362) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.InternalEngine$ExternalReaderManager.refreshIfNeeded(InternalEngine.java:344) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]",
"at org.apache.lucene.search.ReferenceManager.maybeRefresh(ReferenceManager.java:225) ~[lucene-core-8.5.1.jar:8.5.1 edb9fc409398f2c3446883f9f80595c884d245d0 - ivera - 2020-04-08 08:55:42]",
"at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.InternalEngine.refresh(InternalEngine.java:1625) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.InternalEngine.maybeRefresh(InternalEngine.java:1604) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.scheduledRefresh(IndexShard.java:3234) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.index.IndexService.maybeRefreshEngine(IndexService.java:835) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.index.IndexService.access$200(IndexService.java:109) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.index.IndexService$AsyncRefreshTask.runInternal(IndexService.java:967) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractAsyncTask.run(AbstractAsyncTask.java:144) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:633) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]",
"at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[?:?]",
"at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[?:?]",
"at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]"] }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-05-24T20:04:13,937Z", "level": "ERROR", "component": "o.e.i.e.Engine", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "els", "message": " [fincorpus][0] already closed by tragic event on the index writer", "cluster.uuid": "Ic_DMuXJTQqa4zu3wSEobw", "node.id": "12SGfI1qQkyZ-KJjF_okPA" ,
"at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) [?:?]",
"at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) [?:?]",
fatal error in thread [elasticsearch[els][refresh][T#1]], exiting
java.lang.InternalError: a fault occurred in a recent unsafe memory access operation in compiled Java code
at org.apache.lucene.index.ByteSliceReader.readByte(ByteSliceReader.java:73)
at org.apache.lucene.store.DataInput.readVInt(DataInput.java:126)
at org.apache.lucene.index.FreqProxFields$FreqProxPostingsEnum.nextPosition(FreqProxFields.java:501)
at org.apache.lucene.codecs.PushPostingsWriterBase.writeTerm(PushPostingsWriterBase.java:150)
at org.apache.lucene.codecs.blocktree.BlockTreeTermsWriter$TermsWriter.write(BlockTreeTermsWriter.java:937)
at org.apache.lucene.codecs.blocktree.BlockTreeTermsWriter.write(BlockTreeTermsWriter.java:347)
at org.apache.lucene.codecs.perfield.PerFieldPostingsFormat$FieldsWriter.write(PerFieldPostingsFormat.java:170)
at org.apache.lucene.index.FreqProxTermsWriter.flush(FreqProxTermsWriter.java:97)
at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.flush(DefaultIndexingChain.java:177)
at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.flush(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:468)
at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.doFlush(DocumentsWriter.java:555)
at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.flushAllThreads(DocumentsWriter.java:722)
at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.getReader(IndexWriter.java:494)
at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.doOpenFromWriter(StandardDirectoryReader.java:297)
at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.doOpenIfChanged(StandardDirectoryReader.java:272)
at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.doOpenIfChanged(StandardDirectoryReader.java:262)
at org.apache.lucene.index.FilterDirectoryReader.doOpenIfChanged(FilterDirectoryReader.java:112)
at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.openIfChanged(DirectoryReader.java:165)
at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.ElasticsearchReaderManager.refreshIfNeeded(ElasticsearchReaderManager.java:66)
at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.ElasticsearchReaderManager.refreshIfNeeded(ElasticsearchReaderManager.java:40)
at org.apache.lucene.search.ReferenceManager.doMaybeRefresh(ReferenceManager.java:176)
at org.apache.lucene.search.ReferenceManager.maybeRefreshBlocking(ReferenceManager.java:253)
at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.InternalEngine$ExternalReaderManager.refreshIfNeeded(InternalEngine.java:362)
at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.InternalEngine$ExternalReaderManager.refreshIfNeeded(InternalEngine.java:344)
at org.apache.lucene.search.ReferenceManager.maybeRefresh(ReferenceManager.java:225)
at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.InternalEngine.refresh(InternalEngine.java:1625)
at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.InternalEngine.maybeRefresh(InternalEngine.java:1604)
at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.scheduledRefresh(IndexShard.java:3234)
at org.elasticsearch.index.IndexService.maybeRefreshEngine(IndexService.java:835)
at org.elasticsearch.index.IndexService.access$200(IndexService.java:109)
at org.elasticsearch.index.IndexService$AsyncRefreshTask.runInternal(IndexService.java:967)
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractAsyncTask.run(AbstractAsyncTask.java:144)
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:633)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-05-24T20:04:13,941Z", "level": "ERROR", "component": "o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "els", "message": "fatal error in thread [elasticsearch[els][write][T#7]], exiting", "cluster.uuid": "Ic_DMuXJTQqa4zu3wSEobw", "node.id": "12SGfI1qQkyZ-KJjF_okPA" ,
```

Comment: Probably it is a network issue. Could you please post your docker-compose file? How you create your els var?

Comment: Sure @Lupanoide, I've just posted it

Comment: In my-case, ElasticSearch service status is shown as failed, restarted service